# Developing same UI for 3.5, 4.0 (updated 4.7 and 5.5) inches screens in Xcode 5.0.1 (updated xcode 6), no landscape, no iPad and no storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios6, xib

1. I have developed app considering 3.5 inch with .xib files and not storyboard.
2. I am unable to find any tutorial or guide which will help me in designing app similar for all screens.
3. I am using Xcode 5.0.1
4. I am developing only plain app with no auto layout and only **for iOS 6 and iOS 7** (IPhone).
5. Below is the screenshot how it differs on different screens.

   A. IPhone iOS 6 simulator:
    [image: IPhone iOS 6 simulator]

   B. 3.5 Inch (Ios 6 and Ios 7)
    [image: 3.5 Inch (Ios 6 and Ios 7)]
   C. 4.0 Inch (Ios 6 and Ios 7)
   [image: 4.0 Inch (Ios 6 and Ios 7)]

Update:
Please update below answers to also know 4.7 and 5.5 inches screen.
[image]

Comment: consider using auto layout. It is perfect for situations like this. Otherwise you always have to check the bounds of your view if it is a 3.5 inch or a 4 inch device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want check it **Programmatically** :

**FOR Swift**

```
extension UIDevice {

 var iPhoneX: Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436
 }
 var iPhone: Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
 }
 enum ScreenType: String {
    case iPhone4_4S = "iPhone 4 or iPhone 4S"
    case iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE = "iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 5c or iPhone SE"
    case iPhones_6_6s_7_8 = "iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 7 or iPhone 8"
    case iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus = "iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus or iPhone 8 Plus"
    case iPhoneXR = "iPhone XR"
    case iPhoneX_iPhoneXS = "iPhone X,iPhoneXS"
    case iPhoneXSMax = "iPhoneXS Max"
    case unknown
 }

 var screenType: ScreenType {
    switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
    case 960:
        return .iPhone4_4S
    case 1136:
        return .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE
    case 1334:
        return .iPhones_6_6s_7_8
    case 1792:
        return .iPhoneXR
    case 1920, 2208:
        return .iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus
    case 2436:
        return .iPhoneX_iPhoneXS
    case 2688:
        return .iPhoneXSMax
    default:
        return .unknown
    }
  }
}
```

You can check like:

```
print("screenType:", UIDevice.current.screenType.rawValue)
```

For checking **Retina (3.5/4 inch Screen) or Non-Retina**

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
       if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
          // iPhone retina-4 inch
        } else{
         // iPhone retina-3.5 inch
        }
}
else {
    // not retina display
}
```

**Update:**

For checking **All retina iPhone** Programmatically:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
      if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {

           if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667){
             // iPhone retina-4.7 inch(iPhone 6)
           } 
           else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
             // iPhone retina-4 inch(iPhone 5 or 5s)
           } 
           else{
            // iPhone retina-3.5 inch(iPhone 4s)
          }
      }
      else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 3.0)
      {
           //if you want to detect the iPhone 6+ only 
           if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 736.0){
              //iPhone retina-5.5 inch screen(iPhone 6 plus)
           }
           //iPhone retina-5.5 inch screen(iPhone 6 plus)
      }
 }
```

Also check this

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
```

may it will help you .

Happy coding.

Comment: Please update the answer to also know 4.7 and 5.5 inches screen. Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

Put below lines in prefix.pch

```
#define IS_DEVICE_RUNNING_IOS_7_AND_ABOVE() ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define iPhoneVersion ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? 4 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667 ? 6 : ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736 ? 61 : 999))))
```

Now in programming you can say...

```
if (IS_DEVICE_RUNNING_IOS_7_AND_ABOVE()) {
    NSLog("This is iOS 7");
} else {
    NSLog("This is iOS 6 or below");
}


if (iPhoneVersion==4) {
    NSLog("This is 3.5 inch iPhone - iPhone 4s or below");
} else if (iPhoneVersion==5) {
    NSLog("This is 4 inch iPhone - iPhone 5 family");
} else if (iPhoneVersion==6) {
    NSLog("This is 4.7 inch iPhone - iPhone 6");
} else if (iPhoneVersion==61) {
    NSLog("This is 5.5 inch iPhone - iPhone 6 Plus.. The BIGGER");
} else {
    NSLog("This is iPad");
}
```

Comment: Please update the answer to also know 4.7 and 5.5 inches screen. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can use auto layout or code. In code you can use layoutSubviews method. Just check view height to discover is it a iPhone 3.5 or 4 inch and do your set up:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (self.view.bounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        [self.textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        //... other setting for iPhone 4inch
    }
    else
    {
        [self.textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
        //... other setting for iPhone 3.5 inch
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT:

```
if(DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS)
{
//DO THIS 
}
//*********************************************************************
    enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int
    {
        case Unspecified
        case Phone
        case Pad
    }

    struct ScreenSize
    {
        static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    }

    struct DeviceType
    {
        static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
        static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
        static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
        static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
        static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also define globally.

```
#define isIPHONE5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.f)
if(isIPHONE5){

// iphone 5 screen

}else{

// iphone 3.5 screen

}
```